# Reduce release time of multi-tenant azure application

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-webapps

I have a multi-tenant azure application. Inside a resource group, there is a webapp and an azure sql server with one database per tenant. There is also a database which holds all the informations for each tenant.

Each tenant access its application with a subdomain of the application (e.g. client1.myapp.com, client2.myapp.com...). There is a single version of the application for all the tenants.

When I publish a release, I disable the application so nobody can connect, publish a new version to a web app slot, update all the databases of all the clients, test and swap the web app slot and reactivate everything.

The issue is that with every new client, the down time increases for all the clients because all the databases needs to be updated.

What is the best strategy so a tenant can access its application as soon as its own database is updated ?

I was thinking 2 web app, one with the old version and the other with the new version, and an application gateway to redirect the updated clients to the new web app but I don't know how to script that.

Maybe there is a simpler solution ?

Comment: The updates are not backwards compatible? Also, are you upgrading the databases one by one or in parallel? In my opinion having to shut down access due to an update is an absolute no-go

Comment: If a new feature with a db schema change is added, it's not backward compatible. Databases are updated in parallel.